# ios - Resize Custom Views programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, containers

This is just a test project before I implement into something bigger:-)

As per the image I have created 2 custom views inside 1 ViewController. I have a need for them to overlap or at least move out of the way and back again Within the app.

I have tried looking up Custom Views, but i am having much luck.

I was hoping to use this code or something similar:

```
-(IBAction)move02Action
{
   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
       _left.view.frame = CGRectMake(80, 70, 160, 380);  //_left is Left UIViewContorller
       _right.view.frame = CGRectMake(240, 70, 160, 380); //_right is Right UIViewContorller
   [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I realise that that is for UIViews rather than View Controllers. Any ideas on where to look?

[image: Storyboard]

Thanks for the insight:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Containment view controller like this

```
 UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((80, 70, 160, 380))];
 [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.view addSubview:view];

LeftViewController *left = [[LeftViewController alloc] init];

left.view.frame = view.bounds; 
[left  setDelegate:self];
[view addSubview:left .view];

[left  didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self addChildViewController:left ];
```

Check out the ["Implementing a Container View Controller"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.

**EDIT**

1) Add a ScrollView to the self.view and add two views in the scroll view with different frames Use the above suggested code to add the views.

2) set the content off set for scroll View when necessary like this

```
 CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(scrolposition, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollnView.bounds.size.height);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:NO];
```

if you want the effect of over lapping views use  `[[self view] bringSubviewToFront:[self LeftView]];` and  `[[self view] sendSubviewToBack:LeftView];`

Comment: I have been toying with your answer, but that adds a 3rd view and does manipulate the 2 already in place.

Comment: Ok I will look into - more puzzling:-) I'll update it when I got it sussed

Comment: I didn't end up using the UIScroll, but the UIView stuff put me in the right direction thanks:-)